# jQuery Colorbox: Close Colorbox on press submit button

Tags: jquery, callback, onclick, colorbox

I’m working on inserting a MailChimp subscribe form inside the jQuery Colorbox modal window. I’ve got everything to work but I can’t figure out how to close the Colorbox when submitting the subscribe form.

I’ve been looking at Colorbox website and other questions here at Stackoverflow but haven’t got it to work. What I’ve got so far is:

Inside  I’ve added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#cboxContent .closebutton').live('click', function(){
$.fn.colorbox.close();});
});
</script>
```

Then, in my Newsletter Form, I’ve added the class “closebutton” to my submit button, so it look like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="closebutton"></div>
```

But I doesn’t work.
What am I doing wrong?

Sincere
- Mestika

Comment: Do you have any errors output to your firebug console? Try to print something to console in your click function. Try `console.log("clicked")` for example

Comment: You ought to provide more to your question than "it doesn't work". Try to elaborate on the behavior you see after Submit is pressed or better yet, post a link to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Is the subscribe form inside of an iframe?  If so, you would need to call $.colorbox.close from the parent object.  Example:

```
parent.$.colorbox.close();
```

Also, you may want to handle this a different way than on button press.  You should verify that the form has been successfully submitted before closing the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $('#signupform').submit(function(){
       parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close()
    });
});
```

I made the inline content with the mailchimp signup form have the id "signupform".

Answer (score 0):

later of try and try, and see various forums or always in stackoverflow, the function to close that worked for me is this

```
    $("#edit-next").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
        this.submit;
    });
```

You can change the click to submit and working good, this also working for drupal, i find this example in the page of the creator of colorbox.

resource
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/#faq-close